# Calculating with C/C++ using float

Tags: c++, c

I'm practising with C, writing simple programs. The little program     below should just get 3 numbers from the user and multiplicate them. My problem is that i'm a bit confused about the variable type i must use. I want the program to take any number such as *5, 5.673434, 99.123* and so, calculate with them and print out a rounded float number. I have tried many things out but sincerly the result is always false. The program just prints out really big numbers and  confusing character sequences. 
I would be thankful for any advise. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Hello! This little programm will execute a few calculations \nafter you've typed in 3 numbers of your choise. \nPlease type in your first number: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &num1);
    printf("Great. Please choose your second number: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &num2);
    printf("And the third number please: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &num3);
    printf("Ok. You want to use %f, %f, %f for your calculation. Press a button begin.\n", num1, num2, num3 );  
    printf("Multiplication: %.2f", num1 * num2 * num3); 

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Removed C tag because that is C++ code. Note however that if you're using C you should remove the `std::cin` calls, and if you're using C++ you should replace the `printf` calls with calls to `std::cout` and/or at least `std::printf` (along with `<cstdlib>`, instead of the `printf` in the global namespace).

Comment: @Billy -- I won't undo you're retagging, but I think your rationale for removing the C tag is flawed.  This question is not about i/o.  It's about correct numeric type selection.  And the answer is equally applicable to both C and C++.

Comment: @PigBen: Good point. I've removed the C++ stuff, and re-added the C tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to declare the variables as `float`

```
float num1, num2, num3;
```